# How to implement touch event on canvas in WPF

Tags: wpf

I need to implement touch event on canvas. As I have to add many objects in canvas and manipulate them on touch I need to have touch event on canvas. Can any one help how can I do that in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your attempting to move the objects on the canvas with user gestures? If you have Microsoft Blend take a took in the behaviors as there are ones made just for this purpose.

Sorry away from the office or I could give more exact info.